# Pivot Dataframe of start and ending dates into truth table

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame that has the dates that SP500 constituents were added to/deleted from the index. It looks something like this:

```
       PERMNO      start     ending
0     10006.0 1957-03-01 1984-07-18
1     10030.0 1957-03-01 1969-01-08
2     10049.0 1925-12-31 1932-10-01
3     10057.0 1957-03-01 1992-07-02
4     10078.0 1992-08-20 2010-01-28
```

I also have a list of dates that I am concerned with, it consists of trading days between 1/1/2003 and 6/30/2009. I want to create a dataframe with these dates on the index and PERMNOs as the columns. It will be populated as a truth table of whether the stock was included in the SP500 on that day.

Is there a fast way of doing this?

Note: some stocks are added to the SP500, then removed, then later added again.

Comment: what is your expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to find the list of S&P 500 constituents as of a series of dates. Assuming your dataframe has `start` and `ending` as `datetime64` already:

```
# the list of dates that you are interested in
dates = pd.Series(['1960-01-01', '1980-01-01'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')

start = df['start'].values
end = df['ending'].values
d = dates.values[:, None]   # to prepare for array broadcasting

# if the date is between `start` and `ending` of the stock's membership in the S&P 500
match = (start <= d) & (d <= end)

# list of PERMNO for each as-of date
p = dates.index.to_series() \
        .apply(lambda i: df.loc[match[i], 'PERMNO']) \
        .stack().droplevel(-1)

# tying everything together
result = dates.to_frame('AsOfDate').join(p)
```

Result:

```
    AsOfDate   PERMNO
0 1960-01-01  10006.0
0 1960-01-01  10030.0
0 1960-01-01  10057.0
1 1980-01-01  10006.0
1 1980-01-01  10057.0
```

Comment: This works great, thank you. I had to separate the droplevel(-1) into it's own line manipulating the multi-index, but other than that this worked out of the box.

Comment: Better is use `dates = pd.to_datetime(['1960-01-01', '1980-01-01'])` for convert list of datetimes to datetimes like in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Dataframe` constructor with `np.tile`, `np.repeat` with filter by mask created by `ravel`:

```
dates = pd.to_datetime(['1960-01-01', '1980-01-01'])

start = df['start'].values
end = df['ending'].values
d = dates.values[:, None]  

#filter by boolean broadcasting
match = (start <= d) & (d <= end)

a = np.tile(df['PERMNO'], len(dates))
b = np.repeat(dates, len(df))
mask = match.ravel()
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Date1':b[mask], 'PERMNO':a[mask]})
print (df1)
       Date1   PERMNO
0 1960-01-01  10006.0
1 1960-01-01  10030.0
2 1960-01-01  10057.0
3 1980-01-01  10006.0
4 1980-01-01  10057.0
```

Different output like `True/False` table:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(match, index=dates, columns=df['PERMNO'])
print (df2)
PERMNO      10006.0  10030.0  10049.0  10057.0  10078.0
1960-01-01     True     True    False     True    False
1980-01-01     True    False    False     True    False
```